# VB for each line in file, put line in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

How can I in VB get and output, separated by a comma, each line of a file EXCEPT the last line? 
Here is my code:

```
 Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
    ofd.FilterIndex = 1
    If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        TextBox13.Text = ofd.FileName
    Else : Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each line In IO.File.ReadLines(TextBox13.Text)
        TextBox5.Text = line + ", "
    Next
End If
```

An example:

```
line1
blabla
asdfghj
```

Output in textbox5:

```
line1, blabla, asdfghj
```

And NOT

```
line1, blabla, asdfghj,
```

Comment: `Dim Lines = File.ReadLines(...)` //  `TextBox5.Text = String.Join(", ", Lines)`

Comment: @merdolodafoca When a post answers your question you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
TextBox5.Text = String.Join(", ", IO.File.ReadLines(TextBox13.Text))
```

which automatically does not append the last separator.

**Edited to add:** Please note that as a matter of readability, and hence maintainability, you should not try to do too many things in one line. It is not quite pushing it for that one line, but if I were, say, to be constructing a path to the file as well, I would use a separate line with another variable to hold the result of Path.Combine rather than writing it all in one big line.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the values directly in the `TextBox`, first put them in a collection:

```
Dim lines As New List(Of String)
For Each line In IO.File.ReadLines(TextBox13.Text)
    lines.Add(line)
Next
```

Or, even simpler...

```
Dim lines = IO.File.ReadLines(TextBox13.Text)
```

Then once the collection is populated, use `String.Join` to join it by your separator:

```
TextBox5.Text = String.Join(", ", lines)
```